# How to get a function address from current executable?

Tags: c++, dlopen, solaris-10, dlsym, function-address

I need to know the function address from current executable on Solaris 10 using C++ (I'm using GNU g++ 4.9.2). For example, I have a function say as: void doSomething(const char *p), that may or may not get defined in current executable. So, I would like to search for the function in the current executable, if exists, then call that else do some default operation. How do I do that? Will dlsym help?
Please help me with the syntax and the mangled name.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the purpose of dlsym. It will return a function pointer (i.e. address) for a function by (mangled) name.

Comment: @Cameron Please help me the arguments to use (to search from current executable) and the mangled name

Answer (score 3):

You can get a list of symbols in your executable by running `nm exec`.  Or if you are trying to get a symbol from a shared library, you can `nm` the library for symbols as well.  Pick the one you want, and load it with something like ...

```
void* handle = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_LAZY);
void* ptr = dlsym(handle, "mangled_name_you_got_from_nm");
```

Though you will probably want to cast it to the function pointer type of the function you are loading via something like (obviously, change to the appropriate function pointer type)...

```
void* handle = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_LAZY);
auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<int(*)(int)>(dlsym(handle, "mangled_name_you_got_from_nm"));
```

Comment: Is there any equivalent of nm on Solaris 10? That would help me to get the mangled name

Comment: You can go with [elfdump -S](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/elfdump-1.html#REFMAN1elfdump-1)

Comment: This answer suffers from two flaws: (1) name mangling may change between compilers, or even between different versions of the same compiler. (2) Unless the main executable is linked with `-rdynamic` (or equivalent), the function will not be exported in the dynamic symbol table, and `dlsym` will return `NULL` for it.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Solaris 10 does not support statically-linked executables.  See [Static Linking - where did it go?](https://blogs.oracle.com/rie/entry/static_linking_where_did_it):  *With Solaris 10 you can no longer build a static executable. ...*

Comment: @AndrewHenle Static linking has absolutely *nothing* to do with the answer, or my comment.

Comment: @EmployedRussian *Static linking has absolutely nothing to do with the answer, or my comment.*  **Wrong.**  In your comment, you specifically state the executable has to be dynamically linked:  *Unless the main executable is linked with `-rdynamic` (or equivalent)*  Again:  Solaris 10 does not support anything *but* dynamic linking, so your comment is superfluous.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You are mistaken. The `-rdynamic` flag has to do with what symbols are *exported* from *dynamically* linked executable (by default, without `-rdynamic`, *only* the symbols that are referenced by other shared libraries are exported).

Answer (score 1):

The need to "call `foo()` if it is defined, but do nothing if it's not" is quite common in libraries.

One common example is to call `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock` if the program is linked with threads, but perform no locking otherwise.

Weak unresolved symbols are a perfect solution.

```
extern void foo() __attribute__((weak));

void MaybeCallFoo()
{
   if (&foo == NULL) { printf("foo is not defined\n"); return; }
   foo();  // It is defined, call it.
}
```